# GCC compile error - x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/largefile-config.h] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/largefile-config.h] Error 1 (ignored)

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation

Compiling gcc-12.2.0 in Debian linux.  The configure portion is as follows::

```
configure --prefix=/home/me/GCC --enable-multilib --enable-multiarch
```

However, when I run "make" I am getting the error listed in the title.  Do I need additional flags in the configure call, or do I need to not use some of the ones I am using? It says the error is "ignored", but I would prefer to have a clean compile if possible.

TIA for any tips.

Comment: That's not the error message, just a summary. And it also says "_(ignored)_".

Comment: OK - thx for that. I'll ignore it then, but it seems GCC needs to fix this.